# MySQL grouping with search criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

Let's say I have two tables as follows

```
files
------------
|file_id|name|
|1      |a   |
|2      |b   |
|3      |c   |


files_tags_associations
------------
|associationId|file_id|tag_id|
|1            |1      |3     |
|2            |2      |3     |
|3            |2      |4     |
|4            |3      |3     |
|5            |3      |4     |
|6            |3      |5     |
|7            |3      |6     |
```

The question is, how do I get the file names that are tagged 3 AND 5?  In this case c

```
SELECT f.name from files f LEFT JOIN files_tag_associations fta ON fta.file_id = f.fileId
```

....and then I'm lost

Comment: Are you looking for query which returns _files, tagged both_ `3` and `5` - or _files, tagged with at least one tag `3` or `5`_ ?

Comment: I edited my table data a bit.  I need to get the files that are tagged 3 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT f.name
FROM files as f
INNER JOIN (SELECT file_id
            FROM files_tags_associations
            WHERE tag_id IN (3,5)
            GROUP BY file_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) as ft
    ON f.file_id = ft.file_id
```